# Determine input resistance/impedance

Tags: mosfet

[image]

My attempt:
[image]

Any ideas how to proceed from here?

Comment: Need a little more context: Is this DC or AC analysis? Also, are you sure that's where \$R_{in}\$ belongs? Are you certain that's not the output resistance?

Comment: It's AC analysis to find the resistance. It's the resistance seen at the arrow down, technically it should be Rout yes.

Comment: Okay so you _are_ solving for the output resistance. In that case, do you know the small signal parameter of \$r_o\$?

Comment: @KingDuken Forgot to mention, it says to ignore channel-length modulation hence why I don't have Ro in my small-signal model. Also, I've seen in most places they tend to ignore the capacitor when calculating output resistance, does that mean we can ignore it too?

Comment: @Big6 why is that may I ask?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I confused two things. For dc purposes, the caps are treated as open circuits but for ac analysis as shorts (sometimes, mainly in the mid-band range). So that would short out Rs to ground. They are treated like that, because for the frequencies of interest (say mid-band), 1/jwC is "small" enough so as to treated as a short (at low freqs, it is not the case). Notice when w=0 (dc), the impedance of the cap tends to a large number (open circuit), when w is big enough, the impedance may become substantially small. For the low frequency case, you need to account for the caps tho.

Comment: Unless you are ignoring other elements, if you are told to ignore Ro the only possible answer is that Rin is infinite. You can see this by splitting your dependent source and realizing that Vi can only be zero.

Comment: Hmm. I see. I was staring at this for a while and couldn't figure anything out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up a little Edgar Brown's statement:

**YES.** Your notation choose of the output impedance \$R_{in}\$ is infinite.

Assuming that you ignore \$\lambda\$ means that \$\lambda=0\$.

I told you about the small signal output impedance \$r_o,\$ which has an equation of its own:

\$\displaystyle r_o = \frac{1}{\lambda I_D}\$

Since \$\lambda=0,\$ that means

\$\displaystyle r_o=\frac{1}{0I_D}=\frac{1}{0}=\infty\$

Hence, your output impedance \$R_{in}\$ is \$\infty\$. There is no load resistance nor is there a drain resistance. Your work is finished.